# Date masking scala Dataframe

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hive

Is there a generic way to mask all the date/timestamp fields (through auto inference from the schema contained in the Dataframe itself) in a Dataframe to a particular date format without appending an extra column to the Dataframe of the transformed date/timestamp?

Comment: Convert the format and use the same column name as the original column? It will be overwritten so no extra column.

Comment: I believe it'll become a duplicate column, and not overwrite the existing column.

Comment: In this case I'm quite sure it will be overwritten (although I cannot test right now). However, if you were to for example join two dataframes with the same column names then you would get duplicates. Try it out with the `.withColumn()` method.

Comment: @Shaido Thanks, I was under the impression the .withColumn would make a duplicate, but it doesn't just tested it out. Thanks!